# Trying to set something on another GameObjects local position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set a GameObjects position relative to another GameObjects local position, but I'm not having alot of luck. With a raycast I check on which side the player stands, which is all working fine and I'm trying to create a transform relative to the localposition of the object depending on which side you stand on. When this object is not rotated it all works fine, but when I rotate the object the target positions seem to still be in worldspace. I have added images to illustrate the case.

[Album with images illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HebOM.jpg)

```
if(right)
{
    Vector3 Pos1 = _pushableT.localPosition;
    Pos1.x = _pushableT.localPosition.x + distBetween;
    _targetPos = Pos1;
}

if (left)
{
    Vector3 Pos2 = _pushableT.localPosition;
    Pos2.x = _pushableT.localPosition.x - distBetween;
    _targetPos = Pos2;
}

if (front)
{
    Vector3 Pos3 = _pushableT.localPosition;
    Pos3.z = _pushableT.localPosition.z + distBetween;
    _targetPos = Pos3;
}

if (back)
{
    Vector3 Pos4 = _pushableT.localPosition;
    Pos4.z = _pushableT.localPosition.z - distBetween;
    _targetPos = Pos4;
}

targetBallDebug.position = _targetPos;
```

Comment: are those red balls parented to the same thing? its funny how 3 move when you turned, and 1 doesnt.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, the red dots are added in pain to show where they should be.

Comment: Hi! A straightforward solution is to parent the red balls to the cube -- if you can't do that for some reason, then an almost equally straightforward solution is to use invisible marker gameObjects parented to the cube, and on every frame, have the surrounding non-parented dots set their absolute position to their associated invisible marker absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine for position of object, that looks at target, but not ideal for rotation in 3d space

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TrackToTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;

    private Vector3 releativePosition;
    private Quaternion targetRotationAtStartInv;
    private Quaternion rotationDiffernce;

    private void Start()
    {
        releativePosition = target.position - transform.position;
        targetRotationAtStartInv = Quaternion.Inverse(target.rotation);
        rotationDiffernce = target.rotation * transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = target.position - target.rotation * (targetRotationAtStartInv * releativePosition);
        transform.rotation = rotationDiffernce * target.rotation;
    }
}
```